# How to make editingDidEnd not trigger when user tap back navigation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Currently i have an issue in **editingDidEnd** method of swift textfield.
I have a module inside editingDidEnd func to check some validation in B ViewController. If the validation is wrong then it shows popup / alert.

In this case, while user is typing and still focus on the textField, users tap back on navigation bar. it makes editingDidEnd function is also called. So the page is showing A ViewController and also showing pop up.

Is there any workaround to handle this issue? I don't want the alert is showing when i tap back in navigation bar. My expectation is if user press back on navigation. it's not call editingDidEnd function

Thanks Before

e.g.

B View Controller

```
extension bviewcontroller: textfielddelegate {
    
    
    func editingDidEnd(_ value: String, textField: SearchTextField) {
          //showingalert
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want us to write the whole code for you? Just check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think this is not a source code issue ? Since i only need suggestion about what method that appeal the issue ? @HunterLion

Comment: Apart from explicit navigation button taps, the user can use a swipe gesture. Instead of tracking navigation actions, I suggest re-thinking the design.

Comment: can u try adding ```if (isViewLoaded && view.window != nil) { //showingAlert }```

Comment: noted, seems like create button next to textfield, and trigger it manually then oneditingend @lazarevzubov thanks

Comment: It's not working. I think **isviewloaded** is checking current viewcontroller. When user tap back is upcoming viewcontroller. So it's not working . Thanks for suggestion @udi

Comment: What’s called first? editingDidEnd or viewWillDisappear?

Comment: @HangarRash didend called first

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `guard` statement to your `editingDidEnd` method like below.

```swift
func editingDidEnd(_ value: String, textField: SearchTextField) {
    guard navigationController?.topViewController is bviewcontroller else {
        print("DON'T SHOW ALERT")
        return
    }
        
    print("SHOW ALERT")
}
```

I have tested the above code with a simple view controller containing a `UITextField`. However, your delegate method appears to be something different than the standard [`UITextFieldDelegate`'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate)s [`textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting) method.
Otherwise I would have suggested that you could also try experimenting with the [`textFieldDidEndEditing(_:reason:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/2352220-textfielddidendediting) method.